Python: Differences between chocolatey, normal download and mingw installations
As I again somehow destroyed the linking? pathing? (seemed so because there were too many sources), I am once again reinstalling python completely after I remove almost everything I can find that is linked to any python version.
I found some info about mingw being a "complete GCC toolchain" here
A simple explanation of what is MinGW
But as that post is somewhat old, I just in case want to ask if people still use this.
What are the differences between choco, normal download and mingw?
I often work with python from different workspaces (PyCharm, VS Code, CLI) and also often have to configure in some tools where the python installations are.
It seems to me that I have not understood how Python works in the background?
I reinstall quite often, did that about 5 times in the last 2 years and I never had to do anything like that for other programming languages.
Can somebody tell me what I'm missing? Maybe how to prevent this in the future?
Yes, my PYTHONHOME had a lot of assigned paths, but this is necessary for different versions?
If remember correctly, my problems began when I had to install an old version of python, something 2.x. At that point it somehow got worse over time.
I tried messing with the PYTHONHOME values, but it seemed to get worse.

If you need multiple versions, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html, you only need MinGW if you want to compile, choco merely run the silent installer and prepend the path https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-packages/blob/e011266e27b02fdd471c1a2ec22721aa73382f32/automatic/python3-streams/tools/helpers.ps1#L43

I mean, why is it even an option to have multiple python interpreter? A system which automatically detects and assignes newly downlaoded version to a specific folder path would be much easier to handle wouldn't it? I think atleast the venv url you showed brought some light into it. But as I read somewhere, that MinGW is mainly for Windows and not possible? to cross compile, I'm not sure if I really should use MinGW. Or am I misunderstanding again? Does this matter in terms of git or delivering a program to the user?

Ususally, instead of reinstalling, you use pyenv, rye, uv or similiar tools to keep multiple Python version on the same machine. That in combination with venvs makes it unnecessary to mess arround with the syste (PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH, ...)

If you want to cross-compile, just use WSL to target Linux and macOS through osxcross

@MauriceMeyer I usually just downloaded the new version of python from the original website and installed it. Then tried to add the interpreter in PyCharm.. isn't it possible to just update the current venv?

You should not update/change the Python version of an existing venv

So I should completely discard the venv folder and create a new one based on the python path version I want?
